# Cannot connect to SQL Server from a Docker container when using .NET 8

Tags: sql-server, docker, .net-8.0

I have a .Net 8 console app that only connects to a local SQL Server.
When I run( using Visual Studio 2022 ) the app in docker I get the following error:

```
System.Exception
  HResult=0x80131500
  Message=Cannot connect to SQL Server Browser. Ensure SQL Server Browser has been started.
  Source=Microsoft.Data.SqlClient
  StackTrace:
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SNI.SSRP.GetPortByInstanceName(String browserHostName, String instanceName, Int64 timerExpire, Boolean allIPsInParallel, SqlConnectionIPAddressPreference ipPreference)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SNI.SNIProxy.CreateTcpHandle(DataSource details, Int64 timerExpire, Boolean parallel, SqlConnectionIPAddressPreference ipPreference, String cachedFQDN, SQLDNSInfo& pendingDNSInfo, Boolean tlsFirst, String hostNameInCertificate, String serverCertificateFilename)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SNI.SNIProxy.CreateConnectionHandle(String fullServerName, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, Int64 timerExpire, Byte[]& instanceName, Byte[][]& spnBuffer, String serverSPN, Boolean flushCache, Boolean async, Boolean parallel, Boolean isIntegratedSecurity, SqlConnectionIPAddressPreference ipPreference, String cachedFQDN, SQLDNSInfo& pendingDNSInfo, Boolean tlsFirst, String hostNameInCertificate, String serverCertificateFilename)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SNI.TdsParserStateObjectManaged.CreatePhysicalSNIHandle(String serverName, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, Int64 timerExpire, Byte[]& instanceName, Byte[][]& spnBuffer, Boolean flushCache, Boolean async, Boolean parallel, SqlConnectionIPAddressPreference iPAddressPreference, String cachedFQDN, SQLDNSInfo& pendingDNSInfo, String serverSPN, Boolean isIntegratedSecurity, Boolean tlsFirst, String hostNameInCertificate, String serverCertificateFilename)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Connect(ServerInfo serverInfo, SqlInternalConnectionTds connHandler, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, Int64 timerExpire, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, Boolean withFailover)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, TimeoutTimer timeout, Boolean withFailover)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, TimeoutTimer timeout)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, Boolean applyTransientFaultHandling, String accessToken, DbConnectionPool pool)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, SqlConnectionOverrides overrides)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open(SqlConnectionOverrides overrides)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
   at ConsoleApp_Test.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\eangelov\source\repos\ConsoleApp_Test\Program.cs:line 10

  This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
    [External Code]

Inner Exception 1:
SocketException: Name or service not known
```

Code:

```
string connString = "Data Source=ServerName\\INST1;Initial Catalog=MyDB;User Id=MyUser;Password=MyUserPass;Integrated Security=False;Encrypt=False";
using SqlConnection dbConn = new( connString );
dbConn.Open();
Console.WriteLine( "Hi" );
```

Docker file:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/runtime:8.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0 AS build
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["ConsoleApp_Test.csproj", "."]
RUN dotnet restore "./././ConsoleApp_Test.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/."
RUN dotnet build "./ConsoleApp_Test.csproj" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
RUN dotnet publish "./ConsoleApp_Test.csproj" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "ConsoleApp_Test.dll"]
```

NuGet packages:

1. Microsoft.Data.SqlClient 5.1.2
2. Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Containers.Tools.Targets 1.19.5

I tried changing the app to use .Net 6 & .Net 7 and it worked, connected to the SQL Server instance successfully. Also tried connecting via IP("IP\INST1") and the result is the same, when using .Net 8 it breaks and when using .Net 6/7 it works.

Software:

1. Visual Studio Community 2022 (64-bit) Version 17.8.0
2. SQL Server 2019
3. Docker Desktop 4.25.1

Docker file .Net 7:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/runtime:7.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0 AS build
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["ConsoleApp_Test.csproj", "."]
RUN dotnet restore "./././ConsoleApp_Test.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/."
RUN dotnet build "./ConsoleApp_Test.csproj" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
RUN dotnet publish "./ConsoleApp_Test.csproj" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "ConsoleApp_Test.dll"]
```

Comment: "Cannot connect to SQL Server Browser. Ensure SQL Server Browser has been started."  Did you do that?  Or configure SQL Server to listen on a fixed port, and connect to that.

Comment: I do not think the problem is with SQL Server. If a change the target of the app from .Net 8 to .Net 7 or 6 and change the dockerfile to user the images for .Net 7/6 the code works, it only breaks when I target .Net 8

Comment: I'm having a similar issue, though mine reports a handshaking error.  Watching in wireshark, running my test app in windows, it reports TLSv1.2 on the "Client Hello" entry.  Running in docker/wsl, it reports TLSv1.  Changing the project and dockerfile to use .net 6, it works in all environments.  Setting the openssl.cnf into the docker image has not changed anything so far (and it is required in .net 6 to function).  The innermost error is "error:0A0000B5:SSL routines::no ciphers available"  I've checked via interactive session and I have TLSv1.2 ciphers available in the environment

Comment: @TroyBerg I don't think your issue is related. OP is having issues with instance name resolution, which happens using SSRP (SQL Server Resolution Protocol), a simple UDP-based protocol that doesn't use SSL/TLS encryption.

Comment: @EmiliyanIvanovAngelov have you tried using any of the variants to see if the problem is due to a particular distro? e.g.: `mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/runtime:8.0-bookworm-slim`, `mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/runtime:8.0-alpine`, or `mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/runtime:8.0-jammy`.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning Using 8.0-jammy works as expected the others break

Comment: @AlwaysLearning - yes, you are right.  From curiosity, I tried some of the alternate distros you mentioned and the didn't work for me either (not a big surprise).  I'm still messing with it.  I'll make a new question about mine.

Comment: @TroyBerg try use TrustServerCertificate=true; in connection string

Answer (score 1):

I was also having this issue and managed to fix it. I switched to jammy-chiseled images in Docker ([released](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-dotnet-chiseled-containers/) with .NET 8) and the issue was resolved. I suspect this only happens with the Debian 12 OS version used under the hood with mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/runtime:8.0 and mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0.

8.0-jammy-chiseled images use Ubuntu 22.04 and apparently, there is no issue there with SqlClient.

So basically I replaced:

runtime:8.0 and sdk:8.0

with

runtime:8.0-jammy-chiseled and sdk:8.0-jammy

(there is no sdk:8.0-jammy-chiseled image for sdk)

There are other extra benefits of using -jammy or jammy-chiseled images, depending on your needs, you can read more in the Microsoft docs or [this](https://andrewlock.net/exploring-the-dotnet-8-preview-updates-to-docker-images-in-dotnet-8/) article

.NET runtime docker image & tags:
https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-dotnet-runtime

SDK image & tags:
https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-dotnet-sdk

Note: I also managed to reproduce this issue with aspnet:8.0 docker images (Debian)